# Codeigniter: user defined helper function does not load

Tags: php, codeigniter

I made a custom helper extending the system string_helper.php.

I placed it in my `/application/helpers` directory, called it `MY_string_helper.php` as required, unit-tested its functions.

Now, when I try to call one of its functions from a model, it does not work.

The functions in the default string helper work, instead. It looks like my extension is not loaded for some reasons.

Thanks a lot, and happy holidays.

---

Edit: even funnier. I saved the file as `categories_helper.php` in the `system/helpers` directory, and when I try to load it within a model i got the following response: *Unable to load the requested file: helpers/categories_helper.php*

Comment: For now, I think I'll put these functions in a Model. Still, it's so not the way to go, so I hope you can help me.

Comment: I'm sure you already did, but have you double checked your web server user has read access to these files?

Comment: @jfoucher, yep. The whole `/application/` folder is readable. Thanks anyway!

Comment: how are you calling it? I'm sure you have, but you need `$this->load->helper('string');` in your controller, then access the functions like so `my_function($str);`

Comment: @Ross, thanks. In fact I have. The original (system) helper gets loaded and its functions work; my extension does not.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.  I came from windows OS development of my codeigniter project, then shifted to Ubuntu, but somehow it still didn't load my helpers.

I found that changing the naming convention to lowercase solves the problem.  Don't follow what's written in the doc where you are given a prefix to insert, especially if it's in uppercase.  Make use of lowercase.

Comment: That's weird, by changing the naming convention to lowercases solve the problem. Don't follow what's written in the doc where you are given a prefix to insert especially it's in a uppercase. make use of lowercase.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please read the FAQ; Stack Overflow is not a forum, so you need to make sure that when you post an answer it actually does answer the question.  Normally I'd have flagged your post for deletion, but since you then answered the question in a comment, I've edited your answer (so that it *is* an answer) instead.  Please note that you can edit it again yourself if I've accidentally messed it up. :-)

Comment: I know this question was old, but I just had a similar issue. I had a project I created in Ubuntu 12 running in Virtualbox on a Win7 machine. Now using same project on an Ubuntu 13 machine and helpers wouldn't load. changing the name to all lowercase worked, but confused as to why that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

The Codeigniter [User Guide for helpers](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html) describes that helpers are available to controllers and views only.  It does not explicitly mention that helper functions work in models.

> CodeIgniter does not load Helper Files
>   by default, so the first step in using
>   a Helper is to load it. Once loaded,
>   it becomes globally available in your
>   **controller** and **views**.

Comment: That's what I thought too - but then, the system helpers worked okay in the models too.

Comment: create a helper file from scratch, create a simple "hello_world" function that echo's "hello world" or something. Then load it from your model.  Does it work? then the problem isn't the loading of the helper, it may be in the extending or in the function itself.  Care to show the code you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

Linux is case sensitive, Windows no. So, if you are development in OS Windows, before upload your system in a Linux hosting foe example, you need have the names of the files in lowcase.

For example:

In **Windows**: *application/helpers/MY_functions_helpers.php*

In **Linux**:   *application/helpers/my_functions_helpers.php*

Answer (score 0):

mmm, i'm not sure it will work for helpers, but have you tried to load the helper in this way?

`$CI = & get_instance();`

`$CI->load->helper('string');`

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar kind of situation. My development environment was WINDOWS and it worked fine as described in the [DOCs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html) i.e. `MY_string_helper.php`

On the production environment of UNIX, it gave error:

> Unable to load the requested file: helpers/my_form_helper.php

Changing the file name to lower case resolved this error **BUT** the helper was not actually loaded.

After a lot of time waste, by hit and trail it worked [ *it is un-documented* ]

In the autoload.php, just include the mention the extended helper before the default helper:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('my_string', 'string');
```

**Also**, the prefix has to capital, it did not work with lower case prefix:

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to change your helper function name with your prefix like found in application/config/config.php

after helper renamed make sure it contains small letters only

then change autoload file with the function name that you renamed,

main problem because of OS like your Hosting server is linux and you develope with windows so this problem rise