# Codeigntier: Unable to load the requested file: helpers/phpass_helper.php on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu, phpass

I am trying to load Phpass helper in my base controller in order to hash my password. However, it doesn't seem to load on Ubuntu 14.04. I tried to search and some people said it probably because Linux is case sensitive, so I changed my file from phpass_helper.php to Phpass_helper.php. and loaded it by using the code below:

```
$this->load->helper('Phpass_helper');
```

but it's still giving me error said : Unable to load the requested file: helpers/phpass_helper.php. Does anyone know why it doesn't work? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
class PasswordHash {
var $itoa64;
var $iteration_count_log2;
var $portable_hashes;
var $random_state;

function PasswordHash($iteration_count_log2, $portable_hashes)
{
    $this->itoa64 = './0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

    if ($iteration_count_log2 < 4 || $iteration_count_log2 > 31)
        $iteration_count_log2 = 8;
    $this->iteration_count_log2 = $iteration_count_log2;

    $this->portable_hashes = $portable_hashes;

    $this->random_state = microtime();
    if (function_exists('getmypid'))
        $this->random_state .= getmypid();
}

function get_random_bytes($count)
{
    $output = '';
    if (is_readable('/dev/urandom') &&
        ($fh = @fopen('/dev/urandom', 'rb'))) {
        $output = fread($fh, $count);
        fclose($fh);
    }

    if (strlen($output) < $count) {
        $output = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i += 16) {
            $this->random_state =
                md5(microtime() . $this->random_state);
            $output .=
                pack('H*', md5($this->random_state));
        }
        $output = substr($output, 0, $count);
    }

    return $output;
}

function encode64($input, $count)
{
    $output = '';
    $i = 0;
    do {
        $value = ord($input[$i++]);
        $output .= $this->itoa64[$value & 0x3f];
        if ($i < $count)
            $value |= ord($input[$i]) << 8;
        $output .= $this->itoa64[($value >> 6) & 0x3f];
        if ($i++ >= $count)
            break;
        if ($i < $count)
            $value |= ord($input[$i]) << 16;
        $output .= $this->itoa64[($value >> 12) & 0x3f];
        if ($i++ >= $count)
            break;
        $output .= $this->itoa64[($value >> 18) & 0x3f];
    } while ($i < $count);

    return $output;
}

function gensalt_private($input)
{
    $output = '$P$';
    $output .= $this->itoa64[min($this->iteration_count_log2 +
        ((PHP_VERSION >= '5') ? 5 : 3), 30)];
    $output .= $this->encode64($input, 6);

    return $output;
}

function crypt_private($password, $setting)
{
    $output = '*0';
    if (substr($setting, 0, 2) == $output)
        $output = '*1';

    $id = substr($setting, 0, 3);
    # We use "$P$", phpBB3 uses "$H$" for the same thing
    if ($id != '$P$' && $id != '$H$')
        return $output;

    $count_log2 = strpos($this->itoa64, $setting[3]);
    if ($count_log2 < 7 || $count_log2 > 30)
        return $output;

    $count = 1 << $count_log2;

    $salt = substr($setting, 4, 8);
    if (strlen($salt) != 8)
        return $output;

    # We're kind of forced to use MD5 here since it's the only
    # cryptographic primitive available in all versions of PHP
    # currently in use.  To implement our own low-level crypto
    # in PHP would result in much worse performance and
    # consequently in lower iteration counts and hashes that are
    # quicker to crack (by non-PHP code).
    if (PHP_VERSION >= '5') {
        $hash = md5($salt . $password, TRUE);
        do {
            $hash = md5($hash . $password, TRUE);
        } while (--$count);
    } else {
        $hash = pack('H*', md5($salt . $password));
        do {
            $hash = pack('H*', md5($hash . $password));
        } while (--$count);
    }

    $output = substr($setting, 0, 12);
    $output .= $this->encode64($hash, 16);

    return $output;
}

function gensalt_extended($input)
{
    $count_log2 = min($this->iteration_count_log2 + 8, 24);
    # This should be odd to not reveal weak DES keys, and the
    # maximum valid value is (2**24 - 1) which is odd anyway.
    $count = (1 << $count_log2) - 1;

    $output = '_';
    $output .= $this->itoa64[$count & 0x3f];
    $output .= $this->itoa64[($count >> 6) & 0x3f];
    $output .= $this->itoa64[($count >> 12) & 0x3f];
    $output .= $this->itoa64[($count >> 18) & 0x3f];

    $output .= $this->encode64($input, 3);

    return $output;
}

function gensalt_blowfish($input)
{
    # This one needs to use a different order of characters and a
    # different encoding scheme from the one in encode64() above.
    # We care because the last character in our encoded string will
    # only represent 2 bits.  While two known implementations of
    # bcrypt will happily accept and correct a salt string which
    # has the 4 unused bits set to non-zero, we do not want to take
    # chances and we also do not want to waste an additional byte
    # of entropy.
    $itoa64 = './ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

    $output = '$2a$';
    $output .= chr(ord('0') + $this->iteration_count_log2 / 10);
    $output .= chr(ord('0') + $this->iteration_count_log2 % 10);
    $output .= '$';

    $i = 0;
    do {
        $c1 = ord($input[$i++]);
        $output .= $itoa64[$c1 >> 2];
        $c1 = ($c1 & 0x03) << 4;
        if ($i >= 16) {
            $output .= $itoa64[$c1];
            break;
        }

        $c2 = ord($input[$i++]);
        $c1 |= $c2 >> 4;
        $output .= $itoa64[$c1];
        $c1 = ($c2 & 0x0f) << 2;

        $c2 = ord($input[$i++]);
        $c1 |= $c2 >> 6;
        $output .= $itoa64[$c1];
        $output .= $itoa64[$c2 & 0x3f];
    } while (1);

    return $output;
}

function HashPassword($password)
{
    $random = '';

    if (CRYPT_BLOWFISH == 1 && !$this->portable_hashes) {
        $random = $this->get_random_bytes(16);
        $hash =
            crypt($password, $this->gensalt_blowfish($random));
        if (strlen($hash) == 60)
            return $hash;
    }

    if (CRYPT_EXT_DES == 1 && !$this->portable_hashes) {
        if (strlen($random) < 3)
            $random = $this->get_random_bytes(3);
        $hash =
            crypt($password, $this->gensalt_extended($random));
        if (strlen($hash) == 20)
            return $hash;
    }

    if (strlen($random) < 6)
        $random = $this->get_random_bytes(6);
    $hash =
        $this->crypt_private($password,
        $this->gensalt_private($random));
    if (strlen($hash) == 34)
        return $hash;

    # Returning '*' on error is safe here, but would _not_ be safe
    # in a crypt(3)-like function used _both_ for generating new
    # hashes and for validating passwords against existing hashes.
    return '*';
}

function CheckPassword($password, $stored_hash)
{
    $hash = $this->crypt_private($password, $stored_hash);
    if ($hash[0] == '*')
        $hash = crypt($password, $stored_hash);

    return $hash == $stored_hash;
}
```

}

?>

Comment: Is file readable check it by **is_readable('file_path')** may be permission issues.. :)

Comment: Thank you for your input @Praveen Kumar. I checked the permission, it seems fine. The file is readable and writable.

Comment: error : Unable to load the requested file: helpers/phpass_helper.php.check file name phpass_helper.php not Phpass_helper.php. Your direcory migth not be accesible to change permission to 777 and it will work. We do same for laravel in ubuntu. This issue comes when you switch from windows to linux. you can use sudo to change directory permissions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11996661/3568847 try this link

Comment: @Praveen Kumar thanks for the link, i will check it out

Comment: @Bugfixe i will give it a try. thank you

Comment: sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/<siteFolder>

Comment: @Bugfixe  I have changed the permission already, its still not working :-(

Comment: Try loading it using lowecase letters  $this->load->helper('phpass_helper');

Comment: @zachu I have tried already, its not working.

Comment: Can you please post your helper file?

Comment: I have just posted it

Comment: Try loading it as $this->load->helper('phpass'); or $this->load->helper('Phpass'); If that doesn't work change your file name back from Phpass_helper.php to phpass_helper.php and try again

Comment: @zachu I tried everything you told me already, but nothing work :-( . However, really thanks for the input though

Comment: @mayleficent hmmm this is really interesting, why does it not work. Please tell me where do you keep your helper php file is it in system/helpers/phpass_helper.php or application/helpers/phpass_helper.php  ?

Comment: I keep it in application/helpers/phpass_helper.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see in the Codeigniter Docs:

> Unlike most other systems in CodeIgniter, Helpers are not written in
>   an Object Oriented format. They are simple, procedural functions. Each
>   helper function performs one specific task, with no dependence on
>   other functions.

To load a helper, the name of the file has to be like "***phpass_helper.php***"
and inside the controller, you load this way

```
$this->load->helper('phpass_helper');
```

But in your case with the "***PasswordHash***" class I would suggest you convert that to a Library, which would be a better fit for your application and a correct way to apply too.

[Creating libraries in Codeigniter](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

Comment: thank you for your answer, it does help me to solve the problem. After I converted my file to a Library and changed the class name from PasswordHash to Phpass, it works. once again thank you and thank everyone for helping, I really appreciated it.